# jquery close a div with fading and slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a web page.I am using jquery for animation and for an easier javascript.I want to close a div when clicking in a button with a fading out and slide up effect.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: What you have tried so far. show us the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kht98/1/)

You can't do both at the same time (using `slideUp()` and `fadeOut()`). You have to have a work around using `animate()`:

```
$(".button").animate({ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }, 'slow');
```

You toggle the opacity (making it `0`) and also the height (also making it `0`) and give it an animate time of `slow`, but you can make it faster (`1000` is 1 second).

Answer (score 1):

using jquery [.animate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) you can do lots of things, here is an example:

html:

```
<div id="test_DIV"></div>
<button id="test_bt">CLICK ME</button>
```

css:

```
#test_DIV{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:red;
}
```

javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#test_bt").click(function(){
        $("#test_DIV").stop().animate({
            height:0,
            opacity:0
        });

    }); 
});
```

and here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/anChY/)